# Short story about a pilot who crash lands on an alien planet and is nursed back to health by an octopus-like creature with strong maternal instincts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Does anyone know what this story is? Here are the details I know:

- A pilot crashes on some form of embattled planet.
- On the planet there is an octopus mom-type creature.  She is very large and her culture and genetics and species is such that she finds all her joy and purpose in life in nursing young.
- She ends up losing her children and she is fading fast.
- She finds the pilot and nurses him back to health, adopting the pilot (an adult man) as her baby.
- I read it in a compilation of Science Fiction short stories.
- I think I read the story sometime between 2015-2017, but the compilation may have come from an earlier year.
- I believe the compilation was a collection of science fiction short stories, possibly having "science fiction" or "year / year's best" in the title.

I've searched the full text of many sci fi compilations for "Twice-mo, Twice mo, and Barren" - thank you to Nailah for the suggested key words.  I have found no hits as of yet.

It was one of the most heart-warming just incredible stories. Yet I can't find it and I'd love to use it in my classrooms as a lesson in empathy, and perspective taking.

Any help you can offer would be most appreciated - I'm so hoping this forum might be able to help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Possible similarities to Alastair Reynolds' story "Beyond The Aquila Rift"? I haven't read it but there was an episode of *Love, Death and Robots* based on it, there are differences from the question (the alien wasn't specifically maternal) but I don't know if they're in the story or not.

Comment: @DanielRoseman IIRC, "Beyond the Aquila Rift" doesn't include this much detail about the alien's history, or why it is doing this.  And in my memory it is more "insanity-inducing alien spider" than "alien octopus."

Comment: Hmmm. This sort of sounds like it could be Philip Jose Farmer's "Mother." It does involve a crashed astronaut and a mothering alien - only she isn't exactly octopoid and he is placed inside her womb (a large room-like space) where he is fed and nurtured. Her name is Polyphema.

Comment: I read this story too, but I can’t find it either. I remember the octopus-mom named the man “Two Eyes” or something similar, and she kept calling him a girl, because the octopus-babies on that planet were always born female and some became male when they matured. I remember the phrases “Twice-Mothered” (if a female has offspring more than once) and “Barren-Arms” (if a female has no offspring).

Comment: could it be the star beast by nicholas stuart gray?? It matches a lot of the plot points

Comment: @Cassfrank I think "Mother" is the right answer. Also take a look at the cover from https://sciencefictionruminations.com/2014/01/26/book-review-strange-relations-philip-jose-farmer-1960/

Comment: Omg you are all amazing.  yes the twice mothered.  OMG wow.  yayyyy.

Comment: So I thought more about this, and checked the story "Mother" and that wasn't it. (I read a plot synopsis, and it has similarities but its not the one). That said Nailah's comment hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: Left Foot, Right" by Nisi Shawl  The story is set on a distant planet where a human pilot crashes his spaceship and finds himself stranded in an unfamiliar and hostile environment.

The pilot is rescued by a giant octopus-like creature named Mother, who has lost all of her own offspring and is desperate to find a new baby to care for. She adopts the pilot, whom she names Left Foot, Right, and takes him back to her den to care for him.

Comment: It continues to elude!  Shanu the plot sounds right, or very similar.  I just searched and did some synopsis reading, and searched "Barren" and "twice" in the full texts of every short story I could find from both Nisi Shawl, and Nalo Hopkinson but I wasn't able to find the story connected two either of these women.  (Although they do seem like very interesting authors both, in their own right)

Left Foot, Right seems to be written by Nalo Hopkinson and this isn't it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is a novelette titled [*A Mother's Arms*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1984203) by
Sarina Dorie. I too was moved by this book and it really stayed with me.

I read it in a copy of *[The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction (March/April 2016)](https://www.sfsite.com/fsf/toc1603.htm)* and the story can also be found in her book *[Won't You Be My Neighbor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wont-You-Neighbor-Otherworldly-Collection-ebook/dp/B08W25PVYQ)?*.

Opening:

> I was what my people called eightblessed, one child for each of my arms. I rested in the immense boughs of the flowering nectar tree. Each of my outstretched tentacles tended to a baby octopillar. My babies tangled themselves in leafy twigs and experimentally suctioncupped their tentacles to themselves and me. I had never felt more full of pride and joy as I did when I birthed my litter

Comment: Hello @pupgirl I just wanted to write with my gratitude.  If anyone knows of a way that I can donate my social capital to pup girl please tell me.  I previously put a bounty on this question and it remained unanswered but that's not the case anymore!

An absolute celebration! So much gratitude to you!

Comment: Vincent, I am so happy I was able to help! :-)